# WPF View constructor called on windows switch user or remote desktop login

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF Window containing a `ContentControl` that uses a `DataTemplate` which is defined in the windows' resources:

```
<Window (...)>
    <Control.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainVM}">
            <local:MainView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Control.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />

    <!--<local:MainView /> This Works as expected -->
</Window>
```

For testing, the `MainView` is a normal wpf usercontrol with no content.

In my MainWindow constructor I set the datacontext once:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new MainVM();
}
```

Normally, I expect the `MainView` constructor to be called exactly once if I never change the `DataContext` of my window.

**However, it is called every time I log onto my machine using remote desktop or when I just press "Switch User" and relogin:**

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // <--- this is called upon loggin on
}
```

- Neither the window `DataContextChanged` event nor the `MainView.Unloaded` event are called.
- This only happens on my Windows 10 Pro 64-bit v1511 machine, but not on a Windows 7 PC.
- It also only happens if I use the `ContentControl`, not if I just create the MainView directly.
- If the screen is just locked, it does not happen.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or how I can prevent that?

I have found other posts on StackOverflow that might address the same problem:

[WPF: Prevent unload & load after RDP (dis)connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061226/wpf-prevent-unload-load-after-rdp-disconnect)

[WPF re-invoke constructor when connect using Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) to pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715478/wpf-re-invoke-constructor-when-connect-using-remote-desktop-connection-rdp-to)

Comment: Does anybody have the same problem?