# WPF re-invoke constructor when connect using Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) to pc

Tags: wpf, mvvm, rdp

We have an ItemControl that UserConrols will be added to it, the code is as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CamerasList}" x:Name="AllCamerasControl">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SingleView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Constructor of UserControl is as follows:

```
public SingleCameraView()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new SingleViewModel();
        }
```

The problem is that when we open a Remote Desktop Connect to the PC that application is running,  the constructor of the usercontrol class gets invoked and after that we got stuck in different problems.

I read this link [WPF: Prevent unload & load after RDP (dis)connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061226/wpf-prevent-unload-load-after-rdp-disconnect) , but I can not resolve this issue.

Can anyone help that how can resolve this issue?